# How can I check validation of date dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can I check validation of my date input filed, when someone input date to check it, is it right or wrong format. How to do that with js.

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
        Year <small>(dd.mm.yyyy)</small>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.year, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var v = this.value;  
  if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {  
        this.value = v + '/';  
    } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {  
        this.value = v + '/';  
    }
```

Comment: This is ok for . and /, but when I type year example. 20254 it's accept it, but I want someone to type correct date 2020,2025,2008, not 20546. Only four numbers.

Comment: Then you can take maxlength like maxlenght="10"

Comment: Do you mean in js or harcode in html code?

Comment: var datecheck=moment("05.22.2012", 'MM.DD.YYYY',true).isValid();if(datecheck==true){}else if(datecheck==false){alert("Please Enter Correct Date")}             ............I Hope this is usefull for you

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.